# How to limit the results for every object in session.query

Tags: sqlite, session, limit

I am querying my data with session.query to get country, price, and points back. I only need 30 results for each country.

I have tried to add limit(30).all() but that gave me only 30 results back overall. Also tried limit(5).from_self().\ but this threw an error.

Here is the code:

```
df = session.query(Wine.country, Wine.price, Wine.points).\
filter(or_(Wine.country == "US", Wine.country == "France", 
Wine.country == "Italy", Wine.country == "Spain",
Wine.country == "Chile", Wine.country == "Argentina",
Wine.country == "Australia", Wine.country == "Portugal",
Wine.country == "New Zealand", Wine.country == "Austria",
Wine.country == "Germany", Wine.country == "England"))\
.all()
df

# I expect to get a list of 12 countries and only 30 results for each country.   ['US', 235.0, 96.0],
  ['US', 90.0, 96.0],
  ['US', 65.0, 96.0],
  ['US', 65.0, 95.0],
  ['US', 60.0, 95.0],
  ['US', 48.0, 95.0], etc
```

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 3.26.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to handle your requirement using your ORM tool (Python?), but there is a fairly straightforward way to do this using a native query in SQLite:

```
SELECT country, price, points
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY price DESC) rn
    FROM wines
) t
WHERE rn <= 30;
```

Note that this would return, for each country, the 30 wines with the highest price.  You may change the order logic to fit your needs.  If you can't find a way to easily do this from your ORM tool, then there should still be a way to execute a raw query.